# Is there a way to create a Stacked Col Graph with Quantitative Values in R via ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I wanted to try to create a stacked geom_col where the y-value would be the sum of a variety of stats [doing some BBall analysis for fun], and then label each category within the sum. Is there a way to do this?

```
basic <- ggplot(data = basicStats, aes( x = Age, y = PTS + MP + TRB + AST + STL + BLK + TOV, fill = PTS + MP + TRB + AST + STL + BLK + TOV)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: what you are doing does work though

Answer (score 0):

We may do this outside the `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
basicStats %>%
     mutate(Sum = PTS + MP + TRB + AST + STL + BLK + TOV) %>%
   ggplot( aes( x = Age, y = Sum, fill = factor(Sum)) +
    geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```